# Celery tasks get blocked by SSE client

Tags: python, django, celery

I am running a SSE consumer in order to update a few tables like this

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
@worker_ready.connect
def xx_sse_nodes_uptime_info_consumer(sender, **kwargs):
   update_tables...
```

By some reason, other tasks are not triggered when we have a `.delay` calling other tasks. If I remove the task above, other tasks will work normally.

Also, when `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` and `CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPAGATES=True` everything runs fine.

Since the SSE consumer uses `stream=True` the `xx_sse_nodes_uptime_info_consumer` never ends. I am not sure why this blocks others tasks tho as there are enough threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved creating a function for that

```
@worker_ready.connect
def at_worker_ready(sender, **k):
    with sender.app.connection() as conn:
        sender.app.send_task('nodeinfo.tasks.xx_sse_nodes_uptime_info_consumer', connection=conn)
```